# Contact Form 7 - save_posted_data with specific form

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I found a lot of information to save cf7 data to custom posts along with taxonomies and fields using save_posted_data and this works fine for me.

But there is a question left for me.

Is it possible to restrict save_posted_data to a specific Form and use another to save_posted_data for another post type for example?

Example code would really help

Thanks in advance

Buddy

Comment: Well, it´s getting more close (hopefully), No I use if( $form_id == 1903 ) { DO MY FORM FUNCTION }. But now, every other form submission ends up in a loop. How can I return to normal behaviour?

Comment: There is a plugin to do this, [Post My CF7 Form](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-my-contact-form-7/), which will allow you to map a specific form to a specific post type.